# EXECINFO_LIB not found during Building VTK-6.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, cmake, vtk

I'm trying to compile VTK-6.1.0 on OS X 10.9.

When I run ccmake .

To configure the make file, it shows the following

[image]

EXECINFO_LIB is not found. Can anyone tell me, what I can do? Is there any way to locate the library manually and mention it in the configuration.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

About libexecinfo:

> This is a quick-n-dirty BSD licensed clone of backtrace facility found
>   in the GNU libc, mainly intended for porting linuxish code to BSD
>   platforms, however it can be used at any platform which has a gcc
>   compiler.

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/url.cgi?ports/devel/libexecinfo/pkg-descr

Don't worry about it, just go ahead, configure by pressing [c] and next you should press [g] to generate a makefile or a XCode project to build it.